# how to remove a phantom volume reading same data of another volume

Tags: windows, windows-10

At first H volume letter appeared empty but after restarting, it now reads the same data of another existing volume.

It doesn't show up in Disk Management, however, when I try "h:" in Command Prompt it's accepted.

Also, it doesn't show up in diskpart "list volume".

Are there any solutions?

here is a picture of phantom H volume reading same as F volume:

[image]

Comment: What is the output of running `subst` in a cmd shell?

Comment: @DavidPostill it outputs nothing at all. I tried it normal and as administrator.